# Why doesn't Perl's XML::LibXML module (specifically XPathContext) evaluate positions?

Tags: perl, position, xml-libxml

I have an XML representation of a document that has the form:

```
<response>
  <paragraph>
    <sentence id="1">Hey</sentence>
    <sentence id="2">Hello</sentence>
  </paragraph>
</response>
```

I'm trying to use XML::LibXML to parse a document and get the position of the sentences.

```
my $root_node = XML::LibXML->load_xml( ... )->documentElement;
foreach my $sentence_node ( $root_node->findnodes('//sentence')->get_nodelist ){
  print $sentence_node->find( 'position()' );
}
```

The error I get is "XPath error : Invalid context position error".  I've read up on the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~pajas/XML-LibXML-XPathContext-0.07/XPathContext.pm) and found this interesting tidbit

> evaluating XPath function position() in the initial context raises an XPath error

My problem is that I have no idea what to do with this information.  What is the 'initial context'?  How do I make the engine automatically track the context position?

---

Re: @Dan

Appreciate the answer. I tried your example and it worked. In my code, I was assuming context to be the node represented by my perl variable. So, $sentence->find( 'position()' ) I wanted to be './position()'. Despite seeing a working example, I still can't do

```
foreach my $sentence ...
  my $id = $sentence->getAttribute('id');
  print $root_node->findvalue( '//sentence[@id=' . "$id]/position()");
```

I can, however, do

```
$root_node->findvalue( '//sentence[@id=' . "$id]/text()");
```

Can position() only be used to limit a query like you have?

Answer (score 2):

`position()` does work in LibXML. For example see

```
my $root_node = $doc->documentElement;
foreach my $sentence_node ( $root_node->findnodes('//sentence[position()=2]')->get_nodelist ){
  print $sentence_node->textContent;
}
```

This will print `Hello` with your sample data.

But the way you're using it here, there's no context. For each `sentence_node`, you want its position relative to what?

If you're looking for specific nodes by position, use a selector like I have above, that's simplest.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is the position of a node I already have.  Does my edited question give more insight to the problem?